# Describing Objects through schema

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

Is there any way i can write following information from Org.

```
SF-Object Name  SF-Field Name   SF-API Name SF-Type SF-Length   SF-Possible Values
```

I intend to write them into csv files.

I was trying something like below

```
 string header = 'SF-Object Name, SF-Field Name , SF-API Name,SF-Type,SF-Length,SF-Possible Values \n';
string finalstr = header ;

List<String> stdObjectNames = new List<String>();

for ( Schema.SObjectType typ : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() ) {
    String sobjName = String.valueOf(typ);
    System.debug('stdObjectNames: ' + sobjName);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(String s : objectFields.keySet())
    {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult lfieldLabel = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe();
        Schema.DisplayType dType = lfieldLabel.getType();
        string fieldType = String.ValueOf(dType);
        String fieldLabel = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe().getLabel();
        String fieldAPI = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe().getName();
        String fieldLength;
        String possibleValues;
        if(fieldType=='String'){
        fieldLength=String.valueof(fieldType.length());}

        if(fieldType=='Picklist'){
        possibleValues=processPicklistValues(s,objectFields);

        }
        if(possibleValues==null){
            possibleValues='N/A';
        }
                string recordString = '';
                recordString = '"'+sobjName+'","'+fieldLabel+'","'+fieldAPI+'","'+dType+'","'+fieldLength+'","'+possibleValues+'"\n';
                finalstr = finalstr +recordString;


    }
}

String processPicklistValues(String s,Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields){
  Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe();
String ps='';
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry s1: p){
ps=ps+s1.getValue()+',';
}
return ps;

}

Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
string csvname= 'OrgMetaDate.csv';
csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
```

Comment: Not posting this an answer as it's shameless self promotion, but our app Drop My Dossier (not even linking it) can dump all of your objects & fields into a word doc for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the object name should be pretty straightforward. Everything else you need is on the [`DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm).

- `getLabel()`
- `getName()`
- `getLabel()`
- `getLength()` (String fields)
- `getPrecision()` (Number fields)
- `getPicklistValues()`

Note that there is a CPU cost associated with describing fields, and you will be better off describing once and caching the result. I would recommend a `Row` inner class something like:

```
public class Row
{
    final String label, name, type, objectName;
    final List<String> values;
    final Integer length;
    public Row(String objectName, SObjectField field)
    {
        this.objectName = objectName;

        DescribeFieldResult describe = field.getDescribe();
        name = describe.getName();
        label = describe.getLabel();
        type = describe.getSoapType();
        length = (type == SoapType.Double) ?
            describe.getPrecision() : describe.getLength();
        values = new List<String>();
        for (PicklistEntry entry : describe.getPicklistValues())
            values.add(entry.getValue());
    }
    public override String toString()
    {
        return String.join(new List<String> {
            objectName, label, name,
            String.valueOf(type),
            String.valueOf(length),
            String.join(values, '||')
        }, ',');
    }
}
```

Then your csv builder can use this inner class to simplify its logic:

```
List<String> rows = new List<String>();
for (SObjectType sObjectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
{
    String name = String.valueOf(sObjectType);
    for (SObjectField field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
        rows.add(new Row(name, field).toString());
}
String csvBody = String.join(rows, '\n');
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, you are awesome :)..Your code is so neat and clean. Thanks a lot :)